# Как сделать ровные линии в xml разметке

Tags: android

У меня есть две `layout` разметки, которые я использую для отображения пунктов списка. Проблема в том, что их средние линии не сходятся на 1 пиксель!!! У меня пуже нервный срыв из-за него! :)

Если убрать параметр `android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"` в последнем `TextView`, второй разметки — все красиво отображается, но с ним отображается вот этот ужас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот разметка первого файла:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black" >

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:background="@drawable/text_view_background_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:background="@drawable/text_view_background_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="46"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/text_3"
        android:background="@drawable/text_view_background_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="46"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Вот второго:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black" >

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:background="@drawable/text_view_background_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:background="@drawable/text_view_background_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="23"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/text_3"
        android:background="@drawable/text_view_background_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="23"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/text_4"
        android:background="@drawable/text_view_background_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="23"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/text_5"
        android:background="@drawable/text_view_background_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="23"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: А почему бы не сделать это через специальные виджеты для отображения таблиц?..

Comment: А проблема скорее всего в странных значениях веса.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, потому что я удаляю, добавляю и изменяю пункты списка.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, так как исправить-то?

Comment: Я бы для TExtView в левой колонке (тот где номера строк) проставил бы ширину в dp. Тогда всем остальным элементам можно вес в единицу выставить и всё должно стать пучком.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а вот проблема в том, что я вообще уберу его, в релизной версии приложения. Это исключительно для моего понимания :).

Comment: Тем более. Ставьте ему конкретное значение а остальные пусть с единицей будут. После убирания всё тоже норм будет)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, сейчас попробую.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, установка фиксированного размера не помогла, но, когда я убрал `TextView` — все заработало! В ответ!

Comment: Т.е. все веса на единицы, убирание первого текстВью и работает?

Comment: Кстати, у вас везде маржинЛэфт стоит. Наверняка из-за него глюк. Зачем они вам вообще?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, чтобы разделять `TextView`. Я их потом серыми сделаю, чтобы не так четко выглядели, но определенное деление нужно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я за Вас проголосовал :). Кстати, заскочите в соседний вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо) Заскочил)